# How to modify jQuery progressbar color in ASP.net gridview?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, jquery-ui-progressbar

I have a Gridview with a column that contains progressbar value. I managed to display the progress for each row but I'm looking for a way to alter the color of progress bar based on another column with Boolean value ( True/False ). If value is True color becomes green. If the value is False color becomes Red.
I've manged to alter a single progress bar color but I haven't been able to do it in a Gridview for each row! The Boolean column is **status** and the progressbar value is in **progress**.

Thanks in Advance!

GridView in **ASP:**

**Updated:**

```
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="progress" HeaderText="Progress" SortExpression="progress" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="status" SortExpression="status" />
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
   <div class="pbcontainer">
      <div class="progressbar"><span><%# Eval("progress") %>%</span></div>
      <div class="value" style="visibility:hidden; height:0; width:0;"> <%#         Eval("progress") %> </div>
      <div class="status" style="visibility:hidden; height:0; width:0;"> <%# Eval("status") %> </div>
  </div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

**Script:**

**UPDATED:**

```
  <script>
    $(function () {

        $('.pbcontainer').each(function () {

            var val = parseInt($(".value", this).text());
            var status = $(".status", this).text();

            var progressColor = "Orange";
            var progressBackColor = "lightYellow";
            if (status == "False") {
                progressColor = "Red";
                console.log(progressColor);
            }
            else {
                progressColor = "Green";
                console.log(progressColor);
            }

            $('.progressbar', this).progressbar({ value: val });
            $('.progressbar', this).css({ 'background': progressBackColor });
            $('.progressbar > div', this).css({ 'background': progressColor });
        });
    });
 </script>
```

**Edit:** I've updated the code but still the color is always Green! like the If statement is not working ?!

Comment: @Guganeshan.T can you help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

In your snippet the value in hidden field is the same as in the span for progress. So you rather use the same value to and make the decision of coloring.

**Updated:**

For e.g. you have let say two rows with value true and false

```
<div class="progressbar"><span>70%</span></div>
<div class="progressbar"><span>20%</span></div>
<div class="status" style="visibility:hidden; height:0; width:0;">true</div>
<div class="status" style="visibility:hidden; height:0; width:0;">false</div>
```

Now you can read the value in each item and color them accordingly.

```
   var progressColorRed = "Red";
    var progressColorGreen = "Green";
    var progressBackColor = "lightYellow";
    var progressLate = true;

 $('.progressbar').each(function(index, item) {
        var progressValue = $(".status").eq(index).text();
        console.log(progressValue);
        if(progressValue == "true")
        {
            $(item).css({ 'background': progressBackColor });
            $(item).css({ 'background': progressColorGreen });
        }
        else
        {
            $(item).css({ 'background': progressBackColor });
            $(item).css({ 'background': progressColorRed });
        }
 });
```

Here' the [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F3KCY/1/) of the same

Comment: I need to make that decision based on another filed called **Status** not based on the value in span! i need that value in span to be displayed on progressbar. I figured my solution works only for one hidden filed! so I've changed my approach but still have an issue with it! i'll update my code in a minute

Comment: the Code is updated would you take a look and give me a hand!

Comment: @pouria I've updated the answer as per your question. $(".value") returns array of items having class "value" so I've just used the .eq() to get specific item based on index. See updated fiddle demo.